# How to use x-editable plugin with meanjs yeoman generated code?

Tags: angularjs, express, x-editable, meanjs, yeoman-generator-angular

I love [x-editable](http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/) plugin and have used previously for angular standalone application. Currently I've generated my project using Yeoman meanjs generators and I can't find the same options like for configuring editableOptions, the way I could do in angular app. Does anyone know where I can configure these settings? Is it using app.use in express configuration? If yes, how do I include editable option in the function.

```js
app.run(function(editableOptions) {
  editableOptions.theme = 'bs3'; // bootstrap3 theme. Can be also 'bs2', 'default'
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try do this in file `moduleName.client.config.js`

and do

```
 moduleName.run(function(editableOptions) {
  editableOptions.theme = 'bs3';
});
```

don't forget to connect the module in applicationModuleVendorDependencies